# how to locate element using xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<a ui-sref="apps.service" href="#/apps/service">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list icon zoom-icon text-info-dker"></i>
  <span class="font-bold"> Service</span>
</a>
```

How can I locate the element?

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("service")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("ui[href$=services]"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`partialLinkText` is case sensitive. Try

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Service")).click();
```

The element is in `<a>` tag, not `<ui>` tag

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[href*='services']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `xpath` with `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and enable as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//a[contains(.,'Service')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use contains in to locate element in this xpath. The below xpath will be accurate.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[contains(text(),'Service')]")

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//a[normalize-space() = 'Service']
```

will select all `a` elements whose normalized string value equals "Service" -- perfect for the example you show.

Be wary of solutions based upon `contains()` as they will also match strings that include additional leading or trailing text, which may or may not be what you want.